# Setting MTOM-enabled property dynamically in Apache CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf

I'm developing SOAP web service using Apache CXF framework. My web-method returns either binary data or plain XML depending on request parameters. Most of requests return binary data, so I configured CXF to use MTOM in service responses.

But this is not always useful: when XML is returned, caller side expects to get plain text/xml document rather than multipart one. So I'd like my web service to dynamically change its binding.

CXF documentation has following example:

```
Endpoint ep = ...; // example does not explain how to get it
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding)ep.getBinding();
binding.setMTOMEnabled(true); // or false
```

Question: how can I get `Endpoint` instance?

I'm using Spring annotation @Endpoint for web-service and @PayloadRoot for web-method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my own marshalled class extended from `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller`. Only single method is overriden:

```
public class Marshaller extends Jaxb2Marshaller {
  @Override
  public void marshal(Object graph, Result result, MimeContainer mimeContainer) throws XmlMappingException {
    if ( disableMtom() ) {
      super.marshal(graph, result, null);
    } else {
      super.marshal(graph, result, mimeContainer);
    }
  }

  private boolean disableMtom() {
    return ... // depends on response context
  }
}
```

The `disableMtom` detects if MTOM is disabled from response context. Web service endpoint takes care to pass this context to marshaller somehow.

By default MTOM is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code if you are using on `server`,

you need to add `import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;`

```
HelloWorldImpl implementor = new HelloWorldImpl();
String address = "http://localhost:9000/helloWorld";
Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
```

From client side

```
TestMtomService tms = new TestMtomService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
TestMtomPortType port = (TestMtomPortType)tms.getPort(PORT_NAME,TestMtomPortType.class);
Binding binding = ((BindingProvider)port).getBinding();
((SOAPBinding)binding).setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

Refer

If you are downloaded the cxf bundle, code samples for `MTOM` Server/Client available on following path

apache-cxf-2.7.2\samples\mtom